# menu bar with toggling buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I have looked around for a solution but I can't find one.

I want to have a nav bar with 4 buttons using `<li>`. I need each button to have an active state when clicked without reloading the page. If the user presses a button all other buttons should be un-active and the one clicked active. One button(all) will need to be active as default when the page is loaded.

```
<ul id="filtering-nav">
    <li><a class="work"><div>Work</div></a></li>
    <li><a class="like"><div>Like</div></a></li>
    <li><a class="news" ><div>News</div></a></li>
    <li><a class="all"><div>All</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if you have given the anchor tag to change the cursor then remove it. the li markup should be something simple like <li class="work">Work</li> unless you have other specific requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it almost the same way like when you are reloading the page.

1) Use "active" class for the active button (styled by CSS as you need)
2) On button click remove active class from other buttons and add it to the clicked button

Html:

```
<ul id="filtering-nav">
    <li><a class="work active"><div>Work</div></a></li>
    <li><a class="like"><div>Like</div></a></li>
    <li><a class="news" ><div>News</div></a></li>
    <li><a class="all"><div>All</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
   var $buttons = $('#filtering-nav a'); //select all buttons
   $buttons.click(function(e){ //on click...
      $buttons.removeClass('active'); //deselect all buttons
      $(this).addClass('active'); //make clicked button active
      e.preventDefault(); //prevent redirection
   });
```

Working example: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/9vDLV/1/)

Comment: +1 very close to my answer and so I am not posting it. :) I am appending the fiddle I have created for demo if you dont mind.

Comment: @naveen: Thanks for the example :) I've added the e.preventDefault function and some comments to the code.

Comment: What a legend, Thanks so much for all your help. wish I had the knowledge of you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        $('#filtering-nav a').click(function(event){
            $('#filtering-nav a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
<ul id="filtering-nav">
    <li><a class="work active"><div>Work</div></a></li>
    <li><a class="like"><div>Like</div></a></li>
    <li><a class="news"><div>News</div></a></li>
    <li><a class="all"><div>All</div></a></li>
</ul>
```